# Use Facebook etc. to Login to Openfire Server from Android Client

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, openfire, google-talk

I am creating an Android app that will have a chat function. I plan to use openfire as the server and to manage other user data in the custom database. I would like to have users be able to login to my server with their facebook or gtalk etc. account without ever creating a separate account on my openfire server. I know about Kraken being able to allow current users to connect to additional accounts on other xmpp servers.

Another option would be to connect to those other services directly from the client, but then I wouldn't be able to track and manage those connections as easily from my central data center. I would have to make additional transmissions to transfer that data back to my servers. It might also cause conflicts because the chat function should only be communicating with other users of my app and not those that aren't users of my app.

TIA for any help you can provide. This is the last major hurdle that I have to overcome before I can start to polish all of the other pieces of my app for an initial release.

[EDIT]
I have an external database. Couldn't I just use some PHP and SQL to edit the database directly to input new users? I have also thought that I could allow a person to login to facebook or some other service and then request information from that service to enter it into the Openfire database if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [User Service plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html) to create users on the Openfire server, but this won't be secure as the client requires the plugin secret to do this.

It would be better for your app to use a separate authentication server; one of its functions would be to create users on the Openfire server via this plugin.

Comment: Wouldn't this still be secure or relatively secure as the plugin secret would be stored within the app and not visible to anyone else? I made an edit to my question.

Comment: You're distributing the secret in some form in every client you ship.  You can't assume it's secure since anyone with the time & inclinatation will be able to obtain it.

Comment: Re part 1 of your edit:  if the database you refer to is the one used by Openfire, editing it directly from PHP means that (a) you're coupling your code to the Openfire db schema, which can change from release to release, and isn't necessarily well-documented; (b) Openfire caching of user db content may produce unexpected results; (c) the server running the PHP is starting to become an auth server.

Comment: Re part 2 of your edit, & Facebook integration in general: your chat function description sounds like it's private (ie only between users of your app), so it seems like you don't really want to use the gateway functionality of Kraken;  and in any case you have to create an Openfire user before adding gateway registrations.

You can use Facebook/3rd-party data to populate the Openfire user, but still need something to orchestrate this: an auth server, or client use of User Service plugin.

Comment: I am going to try this, but it may take me a little while to finish it all. I'll come back here and accept the answer if it works. What if I were to send the plugin secret encrypted over an ssl connection prior to sending the registration information through the User Service plugin? I know someone could probably hack it somehow, but I would think this would be quite difficult. I want security, but it doesn't need to be overly robust. Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: User Service api over https adds a lot of security (protecting plugin secret & user password).  Have fun implementing this.